# spring boot tomcat deployment styles not loading in resources folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, tomcat9

I deployed my spring boot application war file on my tomcat. when running on Intellij it works fine but when running on external tomcat, js files and CSS files in resources folder is not loading..

[image]

after war deployed files are in WEB-INF\classes\static location on tomcat.

do I need to do a special configuration to load these resources?

[image]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>web-based-ssms-data</module>
        <module>web-based-ssms-web</module>
    </modules>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.ssms</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-based-ssms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>web-based-ssms</name>
    <description>Web Based Smart School Management System</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>install</goals>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

this is the parent pom file

Comment: when you deploy war then what you doing on intellij

Comment: when developing it is working but after deploy on external server tomcat it is not working.

Comment: can you show your proper file structure and  pom/gradle file

Comment: why are you running as war, can't you just run as jar

Comment: I want to run this in tomcat so i need a war to deploy on tomcat right?

Comment: @harkeshkumar sure i updated with files

Comment: this is a multi module based project on which you faciing issue

Comment: web-based-ssms-web module

Comment: when you making war that it create all one war or 2 war file

Comment: i'm using thymeleaf for template rendering.

Comment: only one war file

Comment: can you open that war file and check in it your both module are there or just one

Comment: or you can do this way create 2 war each module then deploy on tomcat both by putting both war file in webapp folder

Comment: data module is in as a jar file inside the web module web module has the ui part data module has only db layer. project is running on tomcat perfectly but the problem is js files and css files cannot load.

Comment: Please provide sample URL which you are calling to your js/css

Comment: <script src="plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Using thymeleaf you must use `@{resource}` (Page Context object).

Example:

```
<script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js}" src="/webjars/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css}"/>
```